# How to have a global or public variable to store all textual data in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building an application where i do not want my user to fetch data off an on from the database. What i really want is to have all the relevant data to be fetched from the database inside a public array variable.

What I am currently doing is using a **Public Shared** variable. But I am unable to access that variable from other parts of my application.

Could somebody guide me on this requirement?

Comment: Please specify the exact problems you encountered and show your approach.

Comment: Maybe you could serialize the data into an xml and attach it to the application, in the web-config folder for example

Comment: well, you cant. its not how ASP.NET works. you can store data in Session if you want, does have overhead but is accessible by all pages as long as the session does not expire. But you will then need to persist it somewhere once you have finished working with it and if you need to use it again later. you are not clear though - what kind of data? what is the data used for?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas The data is meant for picture gallery. It includes all text based information like path of the images, category, album description, etc.

Comment: Sure but most of this would be database driven - this is how modern design generally is. you could store it in the database, then read it into a static class (i.e a module) when the app starts up and reference that static class. Whether you want to use a database or not is up to you but as @TimSchmelter suggested in is answer, for your situation and requirement - static classes (module) would be one way to go

Answer (score 2):

> But I am unable to access that variable from other parts of my
>   application.

You need to create a `Public Shared` field or (better) property. You can use a class or [`Module`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx) (similar to a `static class` in C#):

```
Public Module MyGlobalVars
    Public FooAs String = "Foo"
End Module
```

You can access it via class-name + field/property-name:

```
Dim foo As String = MyGlobalVars.Foo
```

You can also use a class which has the advanatage that you can use it's shrared constructor to load the array from database:

```
Public Class MyGlobalVars
    Shared Sub New()
        SomeDbStrings = GetDbStrings()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetDbStrings() As String()
        ' load from db and return 
    End Function

    Public Shared Property SomeDbStrings As String() = Nothing
End Class
```

The class or module must be accessible,

- so if the class is in a different dll you need to reference it,
- if it's in a different namespace you either have to specify the full path like

  ```
  MyNamespace.MyGlobalVars.SomeDbStrings
  ```

  or add the [`Imports` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) at the beginning of the file.

  ```
  Imports MyNamespace
  ```